# Siddgeir - 'Kill the Bandit Leader' quest bugged, can't receive reward and complete quest

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I want to do the [Jarl's quest in Falkreath to be able to build a house](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Lakeview_Manor).

I seem to be stuck at the "[Kill the Bandit Leader](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Kill_the_Bandit_Leader_%28Jarl%29)" quest.

- I was sent to kill the Bandit Leader in Knifepoint Ridge.
- I had not been there previously.
- I killed the leader and returned to Siddgeir.
- I talk to him and click the Reward dialogue option.
- He says he will give me the reward but doesn't give me anything, and
  if I choose to talk to him again I can still see the reward dialogue
  option.
- Clicking it simply doesn't complete the quest.

This is frustrating! Skyrim is a great game but these critical bugs are STILL present.

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by following this guide: http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Use-the-Skyim-Console-to-Get-Past-Broken-Quests-on-the-PC-242822.shtml. Here is what I did:

Open console, then type `ShowQuestTargets`. Use pageup and pagedown on your keyboard to find your quest that is stuck, in my case `Favor154`. Type `Player.sqs Favor154` in the console to see your progress (stage). Finally, type `SetStage Favor154 20`. 20 is the stage that was stuck for me, the dialogue with Siddgeir.